# Problem when compiling "vcl forms application" in turbo delphi for .net

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I have Turbo delphi for .net, and every time that I try to compile a vcl forms application I receive a send/close error message. It has nothing to do with with the applications, because they compile fine in other machines. The error message accuses ntdll.dll. I can compile Windows Forms Application with no problems.

Comment: So what is the difference between these other machines and this particular machine?

Comment: What is the /exact/ text of the message?

Comment: The exact text is in Portuguese, thats why I did not mention it. It's a send/close window. The point is that theres no difference between  these other machines, thats why it looks weird.

Comment: Try posting the Portugese error message. BTW: This is exactly the reason I dislike development on 'local' systems. With non-English error messages, it makes your chances of finding the cause of the actual error much slimmer than when developing on English systems. For server environments this is even more important. I'm not alone on this, I had an interesting discussion about this with Maciej Pilecki (long time SQL Server Guru from Poland) on one of the BASTA! conferences. See my blog here: http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/non-english-error-messages/

Comment: The error message would be something like this: Project1.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. If you were executing some operation, the information you were working might be lost. To know more about this error click here. Options are debug and close.

Comment: @Victor, please provide as much information as you have, else we are not able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed the .NET 1.1. framework?

Comment: I meant reinstall, in case one of the prerequisites have gotten corrupted

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this problem is probably reinstall Windows and everything.